# How can I include multiple preg_replace commands in my function?

Tags: php

When my customers enter their billing phone number I need it to be stored in the format of +614xxxxxxxx

Customers are entering their phone numbers a variety of ways:
0412345678
412345678
+61412345678

I found another StackOverflow post that included a function that simply removed the leading 0. 
I've made a minor change to instead replace '0' with '+61' but not sure if I need to add an 'elseif number starts with 4, replace with +614' ?

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'removeLeadingZero');

function removeLeadingZero() {
    if (isset($_POST['billing_phone'])) {
       $_POST['billing_phone'] = preg_replace('/^0/', '+61', 
$_POST['billing_phone']);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry!!! What is your extract question?

Comment: Sorry I need to add more conditions to the above snippit so that if phone number is 4123456 it also gets changed to +614123456

Comment: Validating and normalizing phone numbers is a tricky thing. Have you considered using libPhoneNumber library? (I think there should be php bindings for the library).

Comment: Why don't you just put if condition to handle it? If the first letter is not 0 or +, adding +61.

Comment: Is the length of the phone number fixed? If yes, you can do this: ```$phone = '+614'.substr($_POST['billing_phone'], strlen($_POST['billing_phone']) - 8);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try firstly removing 0s or +61 from the beginning and then concatenating the result with +61. So:

- 0123456 becomes +61123456
- +61123456 stays the same
- 123456 becomes +61123456

```php
$_POST['billing_phone'] = '+61' . preg_replace('/^0+|^[+]61/', '',
$_POST['billing_phone']);
```

Comment: Just did some tests and this appears to work perfectly.  This is the kind of regex blackmagic I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: @Embercide This is not magic. This is a very simple work anyone can write.